# Date conversion yyyymmddhhmm+000

Tags: powershell, datetime, wmi

I was trying to fetch the details of SCCM MP from WMI by Powershell.
Thing is data i can fetch from WMI but date format is different and i am not able to convert. May be lacking some knowledge.

```
$query = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM SMS_MPInformation " -Namespace root\ccm\LocationServices -ComputerName "test_vm"

$MP = $query.MP
$Sitecode = $query.SiteCode
$MPLastRequestTime = $query.MPLastRequestTime
$MPLastUpdateTime = $query.MPLastUpdateTime
```

The output I am getting is ok but format of the date is a bit different.

```
$MPLastRequestTime = 20191008000158.927000+000
```

Actually it should be like this.

**MPLastRequestTime: 08-Oct-2019 00:01**

Can anyone advise me how can I convert it in above format. WMIExplorer tool is able to convert it, so I know there must be some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from [Ivan Mirchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12009086/ivan-mirchev)'s helpful answer. you can convert a WMI Timestamp like this:

```
$wmiTime = '20191008000158.927000+000'
$date = [DateTime]::new((([wmi]"").ConvertToDateTime($wmiTime)).Ticks, 'Local')
```

If you need the date to be in UTC, do

```
$wmiTime = '20191008000158.927000+000'
$date = [DateTime]::new((([wmi]"").ConvertToDateTime($wmiTime)).Ticks, 'Local').ToUniversalTime()
```

The latter will output

> 08-Oct-2019 00:01:58

**Explanation:**

Although the WMI timestamp is UTC time, the `ConvertToDateTime()` function returns the date in **Local time**, but unfortunately leaves the `Kind` property set to 'Unspecified'.

When you perform a `ToLocalTime()` on it, that method then [assumes it's UTC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) and adds the time zone offset again, resulting in the wrong time.

Because the `.Kind` property is read-only on a DateTime object, you need to create a new DateTime using the converted WMI time in order to set its Kind property to 'Local'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will test it and let you know. Voted Up.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `Get-CimInstance`. *-Wmi* cmdlets are being depriciated never the less and *CIM* should return DateTime in more readable format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will test it and let you know. Voted Up.